# Gradle, creating objects in build.gradle scripts

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, build, dsl

In my gradle plugin I am using other `build.gradle` script, which looks like:

build.gradle:

```
sciptInstance {
    name {
        arrayWithObjects = [
            {
                var1 = "val1"
                var2 = "val2"
            {
        ]
    }
}
```

In gradle plugin I declared container to hold instances of class `ScriptClass`. This class has field `arrayWithObjects`. Class declaration of `arrayWithObjects`'s element looks like:

```
MyClass {
    def var1
    deg var2
}
```

In my `SciptClass`:

```
ScriptClass {
    // other fields
    MyClass[] arrayWithObjects

    // constructor and so on..
}
```

While trying to build script, I receive a cast exception, saying that I cannot cast closure into object. I tried to declare `arrayWithObjects` in `build.gradle` with other parenthesis and so on, but nothing really works. I also do not really know where to look for it. Perhaps some of you have faced this issue before?
Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
To reproduce this:

Plugin:

```
apply plugin: MyPlugin

apply from: 'example.gradle'

class MyPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    void apply(Project project) {
        def examples = project.container(ScriptClass)
        project.extensions.examples = examples
    }
}

class ScriptClass {
    String name
    MyClass[] arrayWithObjects

    ScriptClass(String name) {
        this.name = name
    }
}

class MyClass {
    def var1
    def var2
}
```

example.gradle:

```
examples {
    example {
        arrayWithObjects = [
                {
                    var1 = "val1"
                    var2 = "val2"
                }
        ]
    }
}
```

In main `build.gradle` apply this plugin and invoke any task.

Comment: Please provide a sample project that illustrates the problem.

Comment: Tbh I do not really know what you need me to provide. Problem occurs while creating instance of ScriptClass, because it tries to create array of objects, but objects are probably not declared properly.

Comment: The whole `build.gradle` that illustrates the problem, I've no idea how can I reproduce your problem in order to solve it.

Comment: @Opal please take a look now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/42996265) you can find a demo that solves the problem. Basically you need to use `Map` instead of `Closure`:

```
examples {
    example {
        arrayWithObjects = [
                [var1: 'varvar1', var2: 'varvar2']
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly fine now. As I thought it was syntax issue. Thank you very much for support!